# Is it possible to use Seagate SATA 6G/s SSHD on HP-ZP800?

Tags: sata

I purchased Seagate SATA 6G/s SSHD to replace the HDD on HP-Z800

But it only runs at SATA 3G/s because in Bios, i can only see SATA 1.5 and SATA3 configurations.

According to : http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=3718645&docId=emr_na-c02711513&lang=en&cc=us

apparently, we need the HP 6G/s harddrive.

My question is , is there a way to fix the Seagate 6G/s to make it running at full speed at HPZ800?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That workstation only supports SATA 1.5Gb/s and 3Gb/s drives.  This doesn't mean you can't use a 6Gb/s drive, it just won't run any faster than the port you attached it to can handle (1.5Gb/s or 3Gb/s).  Even if you used an "HP" 6Gb/s drive.

SATA 6Gb is fully backward compatible, so if it doesn't work with another manufacturer's standard 6Gb SATA drive, then it's something HP has done that's out-side of the standard.  Since the notice is also 3 or 4 years old, and newer drives will tend to have less compatibility problems, I'd just throw the Seagate in there and use it (at 1.5 or 3Gb/s) without worry. You make full backups regularly anyway, right? ;)

Comment: yes... i think i am returning the seagate soon, because my friends told me the seagate has 25% failure rate in 3 years, which is really bad...

Comment: The massive fail rate was actually mainly on the 3TB HDs - Backblaze publish a report every quarter - https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hard-drive-reliability-q3-2015/